# Preserving resolution when converting between formats with ImageMagick's convert tool

Tags: image, imagemagick-convert

I'm really struggling trying to understand how to at least preserve if not reliably change density/resolution (not sure what to call it) when converting between file types with sampled images using ImageMagick's `convert` command line tool

I'm starting with a PDF file that has been scanned at either 200 or 300 dpi. I'd like to be able to convert it to TIFF and PNG for use with various OCR and QR code scanning utilities that only accept one of those formats.

The documentation at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php is "minimal" to say the least. Parameters that look like they could apply include the following:

```
Image Settings:
  -density geometry    horizontal and vertical density of the image
  -sampling-factor geometry
                       horizontal and vertical sampling factor

Image Operators:
  -resample geometry   change the resolution of an image
  -resize geometry     resize the image
  -sample geometry     scale image with pixel sampling
  -scale geometry      scale the image
```

I've tried `-density 200` and `-density 200x200`, both with no avail. Conversions to both tiff and png seem to take place at 72dpi independent of the source resolution.

I'd like to know what to use for this particular situation (i.e. preserving the resolution), but I'd also like to understand where I'm supposed to be able to get more documentation, including definition of terms, format of arguments, etc.